# Can somebody point out the error in my recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

This is my code fragment.

Actually I am getting error of `null pointer exception` pointing in the adapter's first line.

Same thing I have done in other project and that is working fine.
I don't know what's wrong with it is? Please help me.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    Tab1RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab1RecyclerView);
        adapter = new Tab1RecyclerViewAdapter(this.getActivity());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

My adapter

```
public class Tab1RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Tab1RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    Tab1RecyclerViewAdapter(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab1_item,parent,true);
        RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
        //soundNamePref = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //soundPositionPref = context.getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return recyclerViewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
       // CheckBox checkBox;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }
}
```

My tab1_item.xml 
where probably the error is because else where everything looks fine .... so plz see this also

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        />
    <view
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

This is the error I am getting.

[image: errr]

Comment: You could try inflating your `ViewHolder` layout without passing the parent like this: `View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab1_item, null);`

Comment: there seems to be something wrong in your `xml`. Please post `tab1_item.xml` code

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the `view` the first letter of `View` has to be capital. it should look like this

```
 <View
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"

    />
```